# AJAX love username verification from database

Tags: jquery, ajax

No response from this script...cant find any errror by myself..please correct if i am wrong at any point

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#name").keyup(function() {
var name = $('#name').val();
  if(name=="")
    {
      $("#disp").html("");
    }
  else
    {
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "user_check.php",
       data: "name="+ name ,
       success: function(html){
       $("#disp").html(html);
    }
});
return false;
}
});
});
</script>
```

here is the url php content for checking the database..it works without ajax

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$query=mysqli_query("select * from user where username='$name'");
$row=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($row==0)
{
echo "<span style='color:green;'>Available</span>";
}
else
{
echo "<span style='color:red;'>Already exist</span>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You're missing the first argument to `mysqli_real_escape_string` and `mysqli_query`. They require the connection object as the first argument.

Comment: can you edit it and send it...i have very little idea about jquery and ajax

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery or AJAX. Read the documentation of mysqli, there are lots of examples of how to call these functions.

Comment: It looks like you took some old code that was written with `mysql_query`, and just added an `i`, and thought that was enough to convert to mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from user where username='$name'");
```

Replace `$conn` with the variable you assign in `db.php` to the result of `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: @hurricane He's wrong, there's no way his original code could possibly have worked. Maybe he switched from mysql to mysqli at the same time as he changed to AJAX.